# User control's common errors (of AutoScaleDimensions and AutoScaleMode) yet to be fixed by only gurus

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

First off, I am totally new to C# and still in the learning process, particularly about `treeview`. I am creating a `usercontrol` with a `treeview` in it. 
But the intellisense (not even close to the compiler's job) captures 2 errors when I change `MyTreeView.cs` code from

```
public partial class MyTreeView: UserControl{...}
```

to

```
public partial class MyTreeView: TreeView{...}
```

And the two detainees

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

with the allegations produced in the Error List as follows

> 'MyTreeView' does not contain a definition for 'AutoScaleDimensions'
>   and no accessible extension method 'AutoScaleDimensions' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'MyTreeView' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't think these two violated any laws in the form and are not bugs but I don't know how to defend them. I might likely change something to have them defend their own cases.

Comment: What is the reason behind this change: `public partial class MyTreeView: TreeView{...}` ? why did you do so?

Comment: Hi Mong, I'm trying to discover things.

Comment: MytreeView as  I suspect is a usercontrol so it has to derive from a from a control class and not a treeview class, Only if you were making a custom treeview you would derive from treeview and then extend functionalities provided by base tree view

Comment: Really, I didn't know that two different things (custom treeview vs usercontrol), I was thinking it'd be Okie if I inheritted `TreeView` to reuse all of its public attributes and methods. Thank you, back to `UserControl` now.

Comment: "to reuse all of its public attributes and methods" you should take a look at the [TreeView class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview?view=netframework-4.7.2) and search for the property [AutoScaleDimensions] you won't find it there. This should explain your error message